# FLASK - display video

Tags: python, html, flask, video

I am trying to use Flask for the first time.
Currently, I am trying to show a local video on a website.
I created an HTML file that displays a video:

```
<source src="../video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

However, the video doesn't display- when the web page is open there is a black box.
Therefore, I changed the source line in my HTML to the following line:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vUC-eLApqLPSW3qIq4kNsiOdIjnm22o7/view?usp=sharing"></a>
```

When running the HTML code the video worked. But, when I am running the code from a python file the video doesn't work, and no error appears

```
from flask import Flask,redirect,url_for,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()[enter image description here][1]
```

Please help me run the HTML file from my python file in a way that the video will display
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBoNm.png

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.html` file:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="{{url_for('static', filename='myvideo.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also make sure to have a folder named static in your project and put your video inside it.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Je6.png)